# Need guidance on how to deploy a universal app using GAE (Beginner)

Tags: google-app-engine

The local development is done!

So I have:

```
api.localhost/   ->   a PHP rest api. Outout is HTTP codes or json. Data served from MySql.  
cdn.localhost/   ->   a CDN for delivering statics image, file uploads   
localhost/       ->   the main web app written in js. using hashbang urls. data is fetched from the rest API.  
iOs app          ->   objective-c. uses NSURLConnection and NSJSONserialization to parse data served from api.localhost
Android app      ->   same as iOS app.
```

Now its time to deploy. And Im confused. I have read a lot on GAE api guide.

1. Blobstore is not available for PHP, right?
2. How shall I proceed with GAE? There is this normal GAE app engine but then there are some services for iOS and andorid?
3. I need to serve the JSON data and images from API.domain.TLD and CDN.domain.TLD. Does it mean that I have to create three diffrent GAE apps? if no, how should I fetch the images urls?
4. What mistakes should I avoid?
5. What are the best practices for this kind of project on GAE?

Please write as much as you can. Im sure your answer will help many other GAE beginners.

Comment: I suggest you break these down into individual questions and re-ask, it's a bit broad for a single question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use [Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/) instead - it has more features than blobstore.
2. Which services??
3. You can have [multiple custom domains](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain) on one GAE app.
4. Read all the GAE/PHP docs.
5. For serving static images set the [cache expiration](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Static_cache_expiration). This will speed up the serving and lower the cost.